# How to get date fields in php?

Tags: php

How can I get the value of a date in php?
For example I have a date like this:

`$date = "2013-01-29";`

And what I want is to get the year the month and the day and assign it in a variable.

**Example:**

```
$year = "2013";

$month = "01";

$day = "29";
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php), which converts a string of various formats to a date. It can detect various formats of dates:

```
$date_unix = strtotime($date);
$year = date("Y", $date_unix);
$month = date("m", $date_unix);
$day = date("d", $date_unix);
```

Also see [date()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) for a list of all modifiers.

Answer (score 4):

A more OOP way than @TobSpr would be using [`DateTime`](http://PHP.net/datetime)

```
$date = "2013-01-29";
$dt = new DateTime($date);

echo $dt->format('Y');
```

This have the advantage that we have full control over the date, we can even specify a specific timezone, handle poorly formatted input date strings (DateTime __construct will throw an exception on unparsable input)

```
$date = "2013-01-29 invalid";
try {
    $dt = new DateTime($date);
    echo $dt->format('Y');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    printf('Failed to decode input date "%s", PHP said: %s', $date, $e->getMessage());
}
```

For information on what you can send into `DateTime::format`, see [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: +1 for the only valid answer posted so far.

Comment: +1 I never saw that, but it sounds as the better solution

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-01-29');
echo $date->format("Y");
echo $date->format("m");
echo $date->format("d");
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple

```
$newdate=explode("-",$date);
$day=$newdate[2];
$month=$newdate[1];
$year=$newdate[0];
```

Comment: Thats not a proper way for the solution..

Comment: ok....thank you for your valuable comment.....i do not think that there is only one solution.

Answer (score -2):

in php you can do it in following way
              $date=" 2013-01-29"; 
              $tem=explode("-",$date);
              $year=$tem[0];
              $month=$temp[1];
              $day=$temp[2];